# Android/Java Loop Not Working Properly

Tags: java, android

I have 2 array lists

```
ArrayList<Character> answer = new ArrayList<Character>();
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Answer one contains a bunch of chars from the String correctA and the buttons has 20 buttons saved in to it. What i am trying to do is grab each letter from the answers array and assign each letter to an individual button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonStuff();

    //split string and add to array
    String correctA = "TestAnswer";
    for(char a : correctA.toCharArray()){
        answer.add(a);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(answer);

    Button btn;
    //in this case will loop 10 times as there are 10 characters in "testAnswer"
    for(int i = 0; i < answer.size(); i++){
        Random myRandomizer = new Random();
        btn = buttons.get(myRandomizer.nextInt(buttons.size()));
        char a = answer.get(myRandomizer.nextInt(answer.size()));
            btn.setText(String.valueOf(a));
    } 
}
```

I have tried a few different ways with random and everytime i run the app only 7 or 8 buttons are filled with a letter instead of the 10 that it should, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: random can return the same value multiple times

Comment: I have tried using the Math.random and same output, is there a way i can do this and not duplicate the numbers?

Comment: just save the results in an array or something and check each time if it is repeated.

Comment: How can i tell what the random number was though? if i call it again in the loop it will pick a new number

Comment: This is a shuffle. As well as `Collections.shuffle(answer)` you need something like `Collections.shuffle(buttons)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are choosing a random `Button` and a random `char` each time, but over the course of an entire loop, it is very likely that a `Button` is chosen twice, leaving another `Button` untouched.

You have already shuffled the letters in `correctA`, so they are already randomized.  Just pick each button and each char in order.

```
for(int i = 0; i < answer.size(); i++){
    btn = buttons.get(i);
    char a = answer.get(i);
    btn.setText(String.valueOf(a));
}
```

Comment: Yeah its for a quiz game though like the logo quiz games where there are 20 buttons with the letters all mixed up and the user has to find which letters make up the correct answer. So if i use your code the first(in this case) 10 buttons would always be a mixed up version of the answer instead of the buttons being mixed. Basically i want the letters on all 10 buttons but to also mix those buttons with the remaining 10 buttons so they are not in order

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your buttons as the random numbers are not unique. You should use something like this to get random but unique indexes for your buttons

```
ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) indexes.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(indexes);
```

You can use the indexes like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < answer.size(); i++){
    Random myRandomizer = new Random();
    btn = buttons.get(indexes.get(i));
    char a = answer.get(myRandomizer.nextInt(answer.size()));
        btn.setText(String.valueOf(a));
}
```